# Remove titlebar in Gnome

Tags: gnome, titlebar, window-managers, x11, ewmh

I have a window in Gnome whose titlebar I would like to remove.  This was easy in FVWM2: I just set the window style to include `NoTitle`.  In Gnome there does not appear to be a similar option.

I recently learned to use `wmctrl` to modify EWMH-compliant window options, but it also has no method to remove the titlebar (that I can see).

There must be *some* way to do this, however, because applications like Audacious can tell Gnome not to display window decorations.

Googling, I found some pages that discuss the issue of removing the titlebar with `wmctrl`, but in each case the solution was simply to `fullscreen` the window, such that the titlebar moved off the screen altogether.  (That's not what I'm looking for!)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it possible to send this as a bug in the GNOME3 bugtracker? How I can report issue?
Maybe the developers will be able to make the official setting to turn off the decoration of the titlebar?
I use PIXEL SAVER extensions on openSUSE tummleweed. But after the next update, PIXEL SAVER stopped working. Debugging GNOME (lg command) showed no errors. I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me to try Googling for `hide 'window decorations'` instead of `titlebar`, and I believe I've found some more options.

Specifically, the `Window Decoration` section of the `CompizConfig Settings Manager` allows one to specify rules for displaying decorations, which includes the titlebar.

I still think there's no way to perform this modification using plain vanilla Gnome (and I haven't looked into `wmctrl` any further), but since the only reason I'm using Gnome in the first place is the easy integration of Compiz, this solution works for me.